# Large constant array in global memory

Tags: optimization, cuda

Is it possible to increase performance by running on a GPU for the algorithm with the following properties:

1. There are hundreds and even thousands of independent threads, which do not require any synchronization during calculations
2. Each thread has a relatively small (less than 200Kb) local memory region containing thread-specific data. Read/Write
3. Each thread accesses a large memory block (hundreds of megabytes and even gigabytes). This memory is read-only
4. For each access to the global memory there will be at least two accesses to the local memory
5. There will be a lot of branches in the algorithm

Unfortunately the algorithm is rather complicated to be show here.

Comment: What kind of computer?  "hundreds and even thousands of independent threads" - that implies a lot of thread context switches, especially if each thread in a runnable (not blocked on on io) state.  Unless this is a parallel computing environment (with hundreds of processors), you might speed up your program by running fewer threads at a time.

Comment: It is hard to say anything once we don't know the branch pattern and memory access pattern. Could you be a little more specific? Or is it gonna be randomly (or at least data dependent) irregular access?

Comment: @thanhtuan It's going to be data dependent access. Very dispersed. Each thread will only access an element once during the calculation. Most of the time different threads will be accessing different elements. Out of N^2 elements in global memory each thread will be reading approximately N elements.

Answer (score 1):

My instinct is to use texture memory aggressively. The caching benefits will beat uncoalesced global memory reads by a mile.

The writes you may need to add some padding etc. to avoid bank conflicts.

The reliance on hundreds of meg or gigs of data is somewhat concerning. Can you carve it up somehow? Hope you have a big beefy Tesla/Quadro w/ oodles of RAM.

That said, the name of game for CUDA optimization is always to experiment, profile/measure, rinse and repeat.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have Tesla/Quadro at hand. But if I could get at least 10 times CPU vs GPU speedup I would consider buying one. And yes, this global memory worries me the most. But I don't see any way to avoid this. Each thread accesses this memory quite a lot and there's no easy way to predict which particular area it will read. I was hoping that if different threads will be acccessing different memory regions they will not block each other a lot.

Comment: 10x is pretty easy to achieve. I've done 1000x before and that takes quite some thinking. Multiple threads reading same location is not an issue if you mapped to texture memory. In fact, you get some data locality benefits from caching and can even exceed theoretical bandwidth. If you have threads stomping on each other for writes though, all you get is non-deterministic behavior.

Comment: @peakxu throwing in numbers is not constructive especially when the nature of the problem is still abstract.

Answer (score 1):

Before I start, please remember that there are two layers of parallelism in CUDA: blocks and threads.

> There are hundreds and even thousands of independent threads, which do
>   not require any synchronization during calculations

Since you can launch as many as 65535 blocks per dimension, you can treat each block in cuda to be equivalent to a "thread" of yours.

> Each thread has a relatively small (less than 200Kb) local memory
>   region containing thread-specific data. Read/Write

Unfortunately most cards have a shared memory limit of 16k per block. So if you can figure out how to handle with this lower limit, great. If not, you will need to use global memory accesses..

> Each thread accesses a large memory block (hundreds of megabytes and
>   even gigabytes). This memory is read-only

You can not bind such large arrays to textures or constant memory. So in a given block, try to make the threads read contiguous chunks of data for the best performance.

> For each access to the global memory there will be at least two
>   accesses to the local memory There will be a lot of branches in the
>   algorithm

Since you are essentially replacing a single thread in your original implementation with a block in cuda, you may want to revise the code a little bit to try and implement a parallel version of the "per thread code" too.

This may not be clear at first glance, but think it through a little. Any algorithm that has hundreds / thousands of independent parts with no synchronization needed is great for a parallel implementation, even with cuda.

Comment: There's no way to organize global memory storage, so that thread can read sequential blocks. Maximal sequential block size is 16 bytes. The reads are very scattered. And Most of the time different threads will be reading different chunks in the global memory.

Comment: Well then, that is one more thing you will have to live without. But if the computations are intensive enough, the reads should not be a bottle neck.